# How to use spread operator to add property to an object, not override it?

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I have this function.

```
function foo(newdata) { 
     utils.method('GET', '/auth', {
        response: {
          data: {
            settings: {
              last_email_notification_shown_date: new Date(),
              email_notifications: null,
            }
            ...newdata
          }
        }
      });
 }
```

But every time I want to update the 'settings' property, I have to pass *all* of it to data:

```
foo(settings {
   last_email_notification_shown_date: new Date(),
   email_notifications: null,
   SomeNewProperty: 'whatever'
})
```

Is there a way to update the 'settings' property in this function without the need to rewrite it whole? I just want to update the property, not to override it.

Comment: Does `foo` have access to the existing settings? Also note that your second code block has a syntax error which makes it hard to tell what you're really doing.

Comment: (Side note: `...` isn't an operator, it's primary syntax; it can't be an operator because it doesn't have a single result value. Doesn't really matter much. :-) But if it were an operator, it wouldn't do different things in different situations [spread vs. rest] and you could use it anywhere. But you can only use spread and rest in specific places where that syntax is defined.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to update the 'settings' property in this function without the need to rewrite it whole?

It's hard to tell from your question quite what you're really doing, but if the goal is to add `newdata` to the existing settings, you're just spreading it in the wrong place:

```
function foo(newdata) { 
     utils.method('GET', '/auth', {
        response: {
          data: {
            settings: {
              last_email_notification_shown_date: new Date(),
              email_notifications: null,
              ...newdata // <============================ moved
            }
          }
        }
      });
}
```

then

```
foo({
   SomeNewProperty: 'whatever'
});
```

If you need to call `foo` with an object with things outside `settings` and also within `settings`, then it gets *slightly* more complicated, but not a lot:

```
function foo(newdata) { 
     utils.method('GET', '/auth', {
        response: {
          data: {
            ...newdata,                     // <========================
            settings: {
              last_email_notification_shown_date: new Date(),
              email_notifications: null,
              ...newdata.settings           // <========================
            },
          }
        }
      });
}
```

then

```
foo({
    settings: {
       SomeNewProperty: 'whatever'
    },
    otherStuff: "foo"
});
```

That spreads `newdata` (including `settings`), but then overwrites `newdata`'s `settings` in the new object with a replacement `settings`, in which we spread `newdata.settings`.